# TikZ: placing square brackets (or open rectangles) perpendicular to lines forming a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a little sketch depicting an experiment (code below):
[image]

At the arrows (under % Outgoing lines in the code) to the right I would like to place little rectangles with their long side perpendicular to each arrow (what would be even better if those rectangles were more like square brackets, i.e. unfilled rectangles with thick lines and the long side closer to the arrow not drawn). The size of such a rectangle should be just big enough so that the heads of the upper two lines can "fit" into one.

Since I have defined the arrows to have the same length and just point away from a certain central point under different angles, their end points essentially lie on a circle.

Any ideas how I can achieve what I outlined above?

```
\documentclass[article]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[patterns]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Beam, upper border
    \fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines] (-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};

    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);

    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm);
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm);
    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(35:1.5cm) arc [start angle=35,delta angle=10,radius=1.5cm];
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm);
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-45:2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[patterns]

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Beam, upper border
    \fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines] (-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};

    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);

    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm);
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm);
    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(35:1.5cm) arc [start angle=35,delta angle=10,radius=1.5cm];
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm);
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-45:2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I hope it's okay to just add my solution as well... I thought people might want to know what I ended up doing.
But credit goes to Peter Grill and percusse, of course! ;)**

As an addition to Peter Grill's and percusse's solutions, instead of explicitly drawing square brackets or combining a normal arrow with a bracket-arrow-head using `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine`, I used a decoration via a postaction and got exactly what I wanted (after I also shortened my path a bit; see the code below):

```
    \draw[->,%
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.5]{]}}},%
     postaction={decorate},%
     shorten >=5\pgflinewidth%
     ] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-40:2cm);
```

[image]

I actually wanted the upper two lines to go into one bracket, so I just made a path there and drew an arrow at the end of that. Lucky me that worked without further fiddling! :D

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Beam, upper border
    \fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines] (-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};

    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);

    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines and brackets/detectors
    \draw[->, shorten >=5\pgflinewidth] (2.2,0.0) -- +(44:2cm);

    \path[decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with{\arrow[scale=2.5]{]}}},%
     postaction={decorate},%
     shorten >=\pgflinewidth%
     ] (2.2,0.0) -- +(40:2cm);

    \draw[->, shorten >=5\pgflinewidth] (2.2,0.0) -- +(36:2cm);

    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(36:1.5cm) arc [start angle=36,delta angle=8,radius=1.5cm];
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[->,%
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.5]{]}}},%
     postaction={decorate},%
     shorten >=5\pgflinewidth%
     ] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm);

    \draw[->,%
     decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2.5]{]}}},%
     postaction={decorate},%
     shorten >=5\pgflinewidth%
     ] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-40:2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Its absolutely ok to answer the question yourself; particularly if it offers another yet unmentioned way. You can even accept your now answer since this on ist the one you chose ;-)

Answer (score 11):

### Method 1: Square Brackets:

If you simply want to add a square bracket, you can simply add a node and rotate it:

```
\draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm) node [rotate=45] {]};
```

If you want it a different size you can use `scalebox`:

```
\draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm) node [rotate=35] {\scalebox{0.5}{]}};
```

[image]

---

### Method 1: Draw the Shape:

However, a better solution is to draw the desired shape with something like:

```
\newcommand{\DrawBrac}[2][]{%
    \draw [red, thick, #1]  #2%                    Start at given coordinate
           ++(-0.5ex, 0.5ex) -- ++( 0.5ex, 0.0ex)% Top Horizontal Line
        -- ++( 0.0ex,-1.0ex)%                      Vertical Line
        -- ++(-0.5ex, 0.0ex)%                      Bottom Horizontal Line
 }
```

Here you can adjust the sizing of this precisely, but with the current values, this yields:

[image]

---

### Code: Square Brackets

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[patterns]

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Beam, upper border
    \fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines] (-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};

    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);

    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm) node [red,rotate=45] {]};
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm) node [red,rotate=35,line width=8pt] {]};
    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(35:1.5cm) arc [start angle=35,delta angle=10,radius=1.5cm] ;
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm)  node [red,rotate=0] {]};
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-45:2cm) node [red,rotate=-45] {]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Code: Draw the Shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newcommand{\DrawBrac}[2][]{%
    \draw [red, thick, #1]  #2%                    Start at given coordinate
           ++(-0.5ex, 0.5ex) -- ++( 0.5ex, 0.0ex)% Top Horizontal Line
        -- ++( 0.0ex,-1.0ex)%                      Vertical Line
        -- ++(-0.5ex, 0.0ex)%                      Bottom Horizontal Line
 }

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Beam, upper border
    \fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines] (-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};

    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);

    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm) coordinate (A);
    \DrawBrac[rotate=45]{(A)};
%\draw[red, thick,rotate=45] (A) ++(-0.5ex,0.5ex) -- ++(0.5ex,0.0ex) -- ++(0.0ex,-1.0ex) -- ++(-0.5ex,0.0ex);

    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm)  coordinate (B);
    \DrawBrac[rotate=35]{(B)};
    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(35:1.5cm) arc [start angle=35,delta angle=10,radius=1.5cm] ;
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm)   coordinate (C);
    \DrawBrac{(C)};
    \draw[->] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-45:2cm)   coordinate (D);
    \DrawBrac[rotate=-45]{(D)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of explicit angle declarations, you can also use `pos=1,sloped` option to get the automatic rotation.

Comment: @percusse: Good idea, but don't think that that will work with the revised method (which yields much better results anyway), although might if a new shape was defined.

Comment: Ow I missed your update and you're right; but yet another approach might be a new arrow type using `\pgfarrowdeclarecombine` to ease the definition process.

Comment: @percusse: An even better idea. You should do that version.

Answer (score 7):

A small addition to Peter Grill's comprehensive answer with a new arrow type using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows}
\begin{document}

\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*[-2\pgflinewidth]{latbrac}{latbrac}{latex}{latex}{[}{]}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Beam, upper border
\fill[draw opacity=0,pattern color=gray,pattern=horizontal lines](-2,0.8) rectangle (2,-0.8);
    % Beam direction
    \draw[->,thick] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
    \draw[latex-] (1.0,0.5) -- ++(80:1.5cm) node[right]{Beam};
    % Slit, uppper part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,3) rectangle (0.125,0.8);
    % Slit, lower part
    \fill[black] (-0.125,-0.8) rectangle (0.125,-3);
    % Target
    \draw[pattern=north east lines]  (1.9,0.7) rectangle (2.1,-0.7);
    \draw[latex-] (2.0,-0.7) -- ++(260:1.5cm) node[right]{Target};

    % Outgoing lines
    \draw[-latbrac] (2.2,0.0) -- +(45:2cm) ;
    \draw[-latbrac] (2.2,0.0) -- +(35:2cm) ;
    % Area element
    \draw[<->] (2.2,0.0) +(35:1.5cm) arc [start angle=35,delta angle=10,radius=1.5cm] ;
    \draw[-latex] (2.2,0.0) ++(38:1.5cm) ++(0cm,1cm) node[above]{$d$} -- ++(0cm,-0.95cm);

    \draw[-latbrac] (2.2,0.0) -- +(0:2cm) ;
    \draw[-latbrac] (2.2,0.0) -- +(-45:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The horizontal arrow bracket looks slimmer than it is shown in the `pdf` file for some reason.

Comment: I really like this solution. I do wonder though: is it possible to have the bracket arrow-head larger than latex-head? Or do I need to create a new king of arrow head for that and combine them?

Comment: Ha, even better! I just used a decoration for that. Going to post my result after I am done.